# Android Packaging Problem "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name "

Tags: java, android, aapt

I updated my JRE to version 7. Then got this error in the eclipse's console window for all drawable resources(one error for each reference of a drawable)

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
> 'drawable' with value '@drawable/checkbox_on').

I have checked the drawables for corruption. I also tried cleaning & rebuilding the project several times. It was working fine for previous version of JRE.

Got the following 2 errors in 'problems' window

> Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\Software\Android\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist.  Unknown Android Packaging Problem
>
> Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. Unknown Android Packaging Problem

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I had missed a corrrupt png. If the problem does not go by cleaning once then it has to be a corrupt drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Android supports Java 7. The SDK system requirements only mention Java 5 and 6... 7 may not be supported yet. Likewise, perhaps Eclipse does not yet have support for Java 7.

Comment: Yes ,i think so ,it support only 5 and 6

Comment: But eclipse opens up. The compiler compliance level is 1.6 so android should have no problem I guess.

Comment: Fixed it. I had missed a corrrupt png. If the problem does not go by cleaning once then it has to be a corrupt drawable.